# How to swap two classes on every element in an HTML page

Tags: unobtrusive-javascript

I have the following CSS on my HTML page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hidden           {display:none;}
    .visible          {display:block;}
</style>
```

And almost every  and  on the page belongs to one or the other of these CSS styles.  What I need is the javascript to swap everything to it's opposite number....i.e. every hidden becomes visible and vice versa.

I was using something similar on an earlier project, but it only lets me swap one thing at a time, and forces me to specify it's ID directly.  What I need is a global 'if visible - change to hidden - and vice versa' script.

The code (which I tried and failed to expand to have this behaviour) is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(divID) {var item = document.getElementById(divID); if (item) {item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'visible':'hidden';}}
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
.hidden           {display:none;}
.visible          {display:block;}
.temp           {display:none;}
</style>

function swap() {
$('.hidden').removeClass('hidden').addClass('temp');
$('.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('hidden');
$('.temp').removeClass('temp').addClass('visible');
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use your javascript function after adding jquery-1.7.2.min.js to the project I'm working on.  It runs (sprinkled alert() commands in it to make sure it was choking), but it doesn't do anything....weirdness.

Comment: Err, to make sure it was not choking...ok, so I can typo with the best of them!  *laughs*

Comment: Indeed it does.  Thank you very much for the help, Manu.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery

```
$('.hidden').removeClass('.hidden').addClass('.visible');
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid adding jQuery...but it seems I have little choice in the matter.  Added and trying using Manu's code below, which I think makes more sense (especially if I try using it multiple times in a session.)